# Why I'm getting exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I need to create a plugin that uses DDL script and do reverse engineering. I'm using JSglParser to parse DDL script, but it gaves an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

When I set this function as main and run it, it works good:

```
public class DDLtoUML {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\win7\\Desktop\\database1.sql");
        FileReader stream = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stream);
        String ss = "";
        String doc = "";
        while((ss = br.readLine()) != null)
            doc = doc + ss + "\n";
        Statements st = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(doc);
    }
}
```

but when I'm trying to call it from another class and run plugin it gaves an exception:

```
private void doFinish(String sqlFile, String destinationDirectory, String umlFile, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    monitor.beginTask("Creating " + umlFile, 2);
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IResource resource = root.findMember(new Path(destinationDirectory));
    if (!resource.exists() || !(resource instanceof IContainer)) {
        throwCoreException("Container \"" + sqlFile + "\" does not exist.");
    }
    String str = sqlFile.replace('\\', '/');
    DDLtoUML dtu= new DDLtoUML();
    dtu.parseDDL(str);
}


public class DDLtoUML {
    public void parseDDL(String sqlFIle) {
        File file = new File(sqlFile);
        FileReader stream = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stream);
        String ss = "";
        String doc = "";
        while((ss = br.readLine()) != null)
            doc = doc + ss + "\n";
        Statements st = CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(doc);
    }
}
```

and this is the exception :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
at diplomski.wizards.SampleNewWizard.performFinish(SampleNewWizard.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:420)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jsqlparser/parser/CCJSqlParserUtil
at diplomski.DDLtoUML.parseDDL(DDLtoUML.java:36)
at diplomski.wizards.SampleNewWizard.doFinish(SampleNewWizard.java:106)
at diplomski.wizards.SampleNewWizard.access$0(SampleNewWizard.java:97)
at diplomski.wizards.SampleNewWizard$1.run(SampleNewWizard.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil cannot be found by diplomski_1.0.0.qualifier
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Comment: See the root cause: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil cannot be found by diplomski_1.0.0.qualifier`

Comment: All the code that an Eclipse plugin uses must be in the plugin or one of its dependent plugins.

Comment: Both classes are in the same plugin project